# Combine a constant column with a variable row

Tags: excel, function, variables, worksheet-function, excel-indirect

For the sake of simplifying what I'm doing, we'll just say that in one of my cells, I'm calculating the slope of a range. For reference, let's say that in cell C1 I have `=SLOPE(A:A,B:B)`. Fairly simple - however, what I really want to do is have my slope only look at values up to a certain row, starting at row 2. For example, `=SLOPE(A2:Ax,B2:Bx)` where. `x` is a variable based on the value of a cell that I have already calculated.

Let's say `x` is located in cell G20, and the value of G20 is `59`. If this is the case, I want my slope function to be `=SLOPE(A2:A59,B2:B59)`. However, based on the formula I have in G20, its value will change based on user input. So G20 can change to `61`, `62`, or `63`, etc., and when that happens, I want that to be reflected in my SLOPE formula. If G20 changes to `60`, then C1 should become =`SLOPE(A2:A60,B2:B60)`. If G20 becomes `61`, then C1 should become `=SLOPE(A2:61,B2:B61)`. And so on and so on....

I'm simplifying what I'm really doing for the sake of example, so try not to think about an easier way to do this. I just need to combine a constant column value with a variable row value, and stick that into a formula.

How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try:

```
=SLOPE(INDIRECT("A2:A"&G20),INDIRECT("B2:B"&G20))
```

Comment: What if the first value in the range was also based off a variable? `SLOPE(Ay:Ax)` ?